# How to redirect a subdomain with subfolders to a domain using the same subfolders and the subdomain itself as parameter?

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess, subdomain, directory

So I would likte to redirect this url:
http://**subdomain**.domain.com/subfolder/subsubfolder/

to:
http://**www**.domain.com/subfolder/subsubfolder/**?parameter=subdomain**

And also using other, more, less or no subfolders.

I found this, but it doesn't seem to work with subfolders:

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
>   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).domain.com$ [NC]
>   RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/?parameter=%1 [L,R=301]

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.org
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/?parameter=$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: On another note, how can you do `example.com/test` to `test.example.com`?